# Effect of TextView display by setting Theme.NoTitleBar

Tags: android, textview, titlebar

I am confused that why i set android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" in AndroidManifest.xml for didn't want the titlebar shown in screen when the app works and why it will effect text in textview??

the titlebar is disappear in my app, BUT in my app, i can select one of object as focused, this object has a imageview and a textview.

problem is when a object is selected, the text in textview in this object also disappear too....didn't shown in monitor, but if i select another object the text appear again.

Thanks & Regards